# Locked myself out of the admin account

Tags: administration, permissions, permission-sets, admin, user-admin

Accidentally gave myself API User permission set and now everywhere in salesforce I get salesforce.com/secur/NoAccess.jsp

is there any way to overcome it consideringI have the only active Admin account?

Comment: You gave yourself a permission set or did you edit the profile? Can you simply delete it through workbench and some anonymous apex? you can also use the tooling api to pass anonymous apex that can run, find the permission set assignment, and delete it.

Comment: If you clicked the checkbox of the API user then you can not use login.salesforce.com or test.salesforce.com. Try creating another user or get all metadata and create a fresh box

Answer (score 0):

[Remove permission set assignments with the API](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000329272&type=1&mode=1)
this might help.
Login to dataloader and use
 `[SELECT AssigneeId, Assignee.name,Id,PermissionSetId,PermissionSet.name FROM PermissionSetAssignment]` to identify yourself.